# Flawed logic in elevator simulation for finding floors

Tags: java, multithreading, loops, concurrency, sleep

So I'm trying to work out how the elevator will work in a single instance. It gets a persons arrival floor and its destination, and moves successfully to the arrival floor. However I'm not too sure how to make this work properly.
It's meant to wait for another Person to be added to the Call queue, but it just doesn't work right.

Here is the run() method in the elevator class

```
@Override
public synchronized void run()
{
    while(true)
    {


        List<ElevatorCall> callsWaiting = new ArrayList<ElevatorCall>();

        queue.drainTo(callsWaiting);

        for(int i = 0; i < callsWaiting.size(); i++)
        {   
            boolean directionToGo = getDirection(callsWaiting.get(i).getDestinationFloor(), currentPosition);
            int floorsToGoForCollection = getFloorsToGo(callsWaiting.get(i).getCollectionFloor());
            int floorsToGoForDestination = getFloorsToGo(callsWaiting.get(i).getDestinationFloor());

            //System.out.println("Elevator is moving to floor #" + callsWaiting.get(i).getCollectionFloor());

            System.out.println("Elevator is on floor " + currentPosition);

            for(int j = 0; j < floorsToGoForCollection + 1; j++)
            {
                boolean wasPersonOnFloor = checkIfPersonIsOnFloor(currentPosition, callsWaiting);
                boolean isDestinationFloor = checkIfDestination(currentPosition, currentElevatorCalls);

                if(wasPersonOnFloor)
                {
                    currentElevatorCalls.add(callsWaiting.get(floorsToGoForCollection - j));
                    System.out.println("A person on this floor called the elevator");

                    //floorsToGoForCollection = getFloorsToGo(callsWaiting.get(i).getDestinationFloor());
                    //j = 0;

                    directionToGo = getDirection(callsWaiting.get(i).getDestinationFloor(), currentPosition);
                    break;
                }

                if(isDestinationFloor)
                    callsWaiting = removeDestinationFromQueue(currentPosition, callsWaiting);

                if(callsWaiting.size() == 0)
                {
                    try {
                        wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                //floorsToGoForCollection = getFloorsToGo(callsWaiting.get(i).getCollectionFloor());
                //floorsToGoForDestination = getFloorsToGo(callsWaiting.get(i).getDestinationFloor());

                wasPersonOnFloor = false;
                moveFloor(directionToGo);

            }   
        }       
    }
}
```

And in my main class I have this code to simulate it.
I'm fairly sure my logic in the run() isn't correct but I can't seem to figure out what aspect of it is.

```
    run();

    Elevator elevator = new Elevator(queue);
    elevator.run();
}

public synchronized static void run()
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    int waitTime = rand.nextInt((1000 - 100) + 1) + 100;
    int startingID = 1;

    List<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>(startingID);

    people.add(new Person(queue));

    for(int i = 0; i < people.size(); i++)
    {
        people.get(i).run();
    }

    try {
        Thread.sleep(waitTime);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help with the logic.

Comment: "it just doesn't work right" is not a description of a problem. When you do come up with the correct description (hint: what did you expect to happen, what actually happened), you'll be much closer to solving the problem.

Comment: I will note, however, that there's *never* a reason to synchronize `run()`, and I don't know why you also have a static `run()`. And finally, you should learn to use the concurrency tools that the API provides: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html

Answer (score 2):

Does your `Elevator` class or `Person` extend `Thread`? Remember that to start a `Thread` you must call `start()` as opposed to `run()`. If it is instead a `Runnable`, you must pass it to a new `Thread` object and `start()` that new thread. Maybe your code isn't advancing because it is stuck in a loop since it's handled in a single thread?

Comment: Both implement Runnable. The code compiles and all just ends up hanging eventually after it gets the first collection floor. What would I have to change in my code?

Comment: Right now this is all running on a single thread. I'm assuming that you want the elevator to have its own thread as well as every single person? If so you should replace `people.get(i).run();` with `new Thread(people.get(i)).start();` and do the same with `elevator.run()`. In your `run()` method for elevator, it is also waiting indefinitely where you call `wait()`. This will stop the elevator from running forever unless you call `elevator.notify()` on another thread. You should read this to understand concurrency: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html

Comment: Actually, you should read the whole tutorial about concurrency (left navigation pane of that link) but that page specifically outlines one of the problems of your code.

Comment: @I can't get it working for elevator for some reason? Says the start method is not in elevator but its working for Person and I don't know why

Comment: It's also a `Runnable`. You need to pass it to a new `Thread` just like you did with the `Person`s. If that doesn't work, then make sure it implements `Runnable`.

Comment: `new Thread(elevator).start();`? If that doesn't work then `Elevator` doesn't implement `Runnable`. What is the error?